# listing wifi networks in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wifi, samba

I have a requirement where my phone will be connected to seagate wifi disk and I need to show the available wifi networks so that user can still browse internet while connected to the wifi disk. So I need a way to get the list of wifi network connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available to 3rd party iOS apps.  (Apple apps that show the wifi information make use of private APIs).

That's the reason why you don't see wifi stumbler apps in the App Store - they were purged 4 years ago: http://www.macworld.com/article/1146906/wifi_stumblers.html

Comment: I have seen couple of apps doing this,https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/seagate-media/id431912202?mt=8 (see the last scene shot)

Comment: I would guess that the way this happens is that it is not the app that asks iOS for the list of wifi networks, but rather that the app asks the Wifi Disk for the list - and then displays that.  If that's the route you want to go, then you need to ask Seagate to allow you to access their private API (as distinct to Apple's private API!)